# Trying to get property of non-object | Twitter api

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

Trying to get the tweet id using below code,

```
$home_timeline = $twitteroauth->get('statuses/user_timeline', array('count' => 4));  

echo "<pre>";
print_r($home_timeline->id_str);
echo "</pre>";
```

**Trying to get property of non-object**

Google alot, but didn't find any proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($home_timeline as $i => $tweet) {
    echo "$i: $tweet->id_str" . "<br/>";
}
```